# How do you specify a file's name as part of the input directory?

Tags: bash, unix

I have files in one directory with the format

> ```
> - 0163-301_02_29_2008_off.nii
> - 0163-301_02_29_2008_on.nii
> - 0164-303_11_30_2007_off.nii
> - 0164-303_11_30_2007_on.nii
> ```

I would like to run a command that involves the names of the files as inputs. The address path would be

> /Users/jjuan/Documents/MTAutism/new_MTR_datasets/UsableNii/0163-301_02_29_2008_off.nii

and so on.

So far, I've this is the code I've written

```
for file in *_on.nii; do

set fileroot = ${file} cut -b 1-78
echo $fileroot

/usr/local/fsl414/bin/flirt -in $file  -ref /Users/jjuan/Documents/MTAutism/new_MTR_datasets/UsableNii/$fileroot_off.nii -out /Users/jjuan/Documents/MTAutism/new_MTR_datasets/UsableNii/$fileroot_ontooff -omat /Users/jjuan/Documents/MTAutism/new_MTR_datasets/UsableNii/$fileroot_ontooff.mat -bins 256 -cost corratio -searchrx -90 90 -searchry -90 90 -searchrz -90 90 -dof 6  -interp trilinear

done
```

However, the $fileroot set doesn't appear in the path specified, and it ouputs only a blank space.

Answer (score 0):

Fix your variable naming, for starters:

```
for files in *_on.nii; do
    ^^^^^- files with an S

set fileroot = ${file} cut -b 1-78
                 ^^^^-- -file WITHOUT an S
```

Comment: Sorry about that, I've since corrected it before but am getting the same problem.

Comment: the `set` is also incorrect. that's not how you invoke cut, or pass a filename to cut...

Comment: Could you help me correct that? I'm very new to bash coding, and am not sure what is wrong with that part

Answer (score 0):

don't use `set`, because it's purpose is to manipulate shell options/variables, instead use this:

```
fileroot="$(echo ${file} | cut -b 1-78)"
```

also make sure to enclose the references to `fileroot` variable in braces, i.e. `${fileroot}_ontooff` to delimit variable name

Comment: I tried this, but it seems to read it as `'/Users/jjuan/Documents/MTAutism/new_MTR_datasets/UsableNii/_ontooff'`

Comment: what is the output of `echo $file; echo ${file} | cut -b 1-78`? And do you need to cut by bytes, going by characters, `-c`, could be easier to read

Comment: I changed it to -c

The output I get is `-bash: local: can only be used in a function
** ERROR (nifti_image_read): failed to find header file for '/Users/jjuan/Documents/MTAutism/new_MTR_datasets/UsableNii/'
** ERROR: nifti_image_open(/Users/jjuan/Documents/MTAutism/new_MTR_datasets/UsableNii/): bad header info`

Comment: sorry, please remove `local`, as the error says, it's only usable inside of functions

Answer (score 0):

I don't quite follow what you want, but if you want to change from `0163-301_02_29_2008_on.nii` to `0163-301_02_29_2008_off.nii`:

```
cd /Users/jjuan/Documents/MTAutism/new_MTR_datasets/UsableNii
for on_file in *_on.nii; do
    off_file=$PWD/${on_file/on.nii/off.nii}
    # Do something with off_file
done
```

The above replace "on.nii" with "off.nii"

## Update

I changed the code to include the full path per request.

Comment: How could I place this off_file into a path? such as
`/Users/jjuan/Documents/MTAutism/new_MTR_datasets/UsableNii/$off_file`

Comment: If you are already inside that directory, use the variable $PWD. See my updated code.